# Python 3.x: Problems writing utf-8 strings to binary txt file

Tags: python, binary

I am currently working through "Learning Python the hardway" and try to alter one Excercise. 
Objective: Write the binary equivalents of the languages in a new .txt file

```
import sys
script, encoding, error = sys.argv

def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)

def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
    bin_file.write(raw_bytes + "\n".encode("utf-8"))
    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)

languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")
bin_file = open("bin_languages.txt", "wb")
main(languages, encoding, error)
```

The majority of this code is from the learning example, that is why there is for understanding purposes an encode/decode of raw_bytes to cooked_strings and back again.

Unfortunately, the output file contains the same content as the original file. Is my approach not possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you **decoding** again, then encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Could you please explain this to me a bit more? When I run the script in the shell, I get a result like "b'Ti\xe1\xba\xbfng Vi\xe1\xbb\x87t' <===> Tiếng Việt". Now, I wanted to write the left side (which is defined as raw_bytes) into a file the way it is displayed. Thanks!
I think this way was just to show how it can be done it book. Everything except for the file_write part is 1to1 from the book.

Comment: @OferSadan : No, i want to write the raw_bytes into a file. The cooked_string are already in the original file. The author tried tp demonstrated just for understanding how to decode and encode.

Comment: Note that `raw_bytes` is displayed as *Python syntax aimed at easy debugging*. The binary data is shown using escape sequences for any bytes not representable as printable ASCII characters. You'll not find literal `Ti\xe1\xba\xbfng Vi\xe1\xbb\x87t'` data in the file, it'll write the bytes for the ASCII codepoints `T` (hex value 54) and `i` (69) and then the bytes with hex value E1 and BA and BF, etc.

Comment: I note that the binary data in your example is **also** UTF-8 data, so writing that data to the file will still show nothing different from the original UTF-8 contents... Also see [What does a b prefix before a python string mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2592764)

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you are writing to the file due to the `"\n".encode('utf-8')` expression in there, and read a little too fast. You could just use `b'\n'` and leave out the encoding. You are still writing UTF-8 data. UTF-8 is a binary encoding of text, it doesn't matter if you open the file in text mode with UTF-8 encoding, or manually encode and write the bytes to a binary file. The result is the same, whether you manually encode or ask Python to do it for you. If you decode from UTF-8 and then encode again *to* UTF-8, then yes, you'll get the same data. That's the nature of encodings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was myself confused when you were arguing!! Otherwise there is no difference for text whether you write it as binary or text for same encoding.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you very much for your help! I think I understand the reasons why it is not working. The author of the book wrote the following challenge: "Extra Challenge: Rewrite the script using b'  ' instead of UTF-8 strings, effectively reversing it". That's why I thought I should write the left side of the output into a new file as a starting point for the new script. So how would be the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @Max: I don't know enough about the exercise to help you there, sorry. The Python community in general [recommends *against* Learn Python the Hard Way](https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints), by the way. Personally, I recommend [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) instead, which is available for free online.

Comment: @MartijnPieters glad that you mentioned that it is not recommended by the community. Will then take a look at Think Python then.